# Netbeans not opening in Ubuntu for a single time

Tags: java, windows

I have installed Apache Netbeans in my Ubuntu using this command "sudo dpkg -i apache-netbeans_*_all.deb". It was installed correctly without any kind of errors. But after installing as soon as I try to open the app it doesn't open. Instead opening the app its directing to the current window I am using. I have searched all the way through to Stackoverflow and AskUbuntu and other different platforms. I got some clues and applied them but all efforts went in vain. Now the app logo is there but I can't open or not even able to remove the app icon form my OS.

I tried to Open the app and expect to use the app. But the case was opposite. It hasn't opened for a single time.

Comment: Being an Eclipse IDE guy I would first recommend ditching Netbeans all together, use IntelliJ. I'm an Eclipse guy but IJ is a lot more popular nowadays. Also there is absolutely nothing you can't do any any of them. Related to your question did you install Java on your environment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.